# Implementing parameters to meta classifier in Weka

Tags: weka, decision-tree, classification

If I am currently using a Weka decision tree (or other) classifier as follows in my Java code:

```
// Get training and testing data.
Instances train = new Instances ("from training file");
train.setClassIndex(train.numAttributes() - 1);
Instances test = new Instances ("from testing file");        
test.setClassIndex(test.numAttributes() - 1);

// Set classifier.
Object obj = Class.forName("weka.classifiers.trees.J48").newInstance();
Classifier cls = (Classifier) Class.forName("weka.classifiers.trees.J48").cast(obj);

// Set parameters for classifier.      
String options = ("-C 0.05 -M 2");        
String[] optionsArray = options.split(" ");        
cls.setOptions(optionsArray);        

// Train classifier.    
cls.buildClassifier(train);        
Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(train);

// Test trained classifier.
eval.evaluateModel(cls, test);
```

What happens if I want to use a meta classifier, e.g. bagging, to try to boost results? In Weka's Explorer, if I use bagging with my training and testing data, the parameter string for the classifier is:

```
weka.classifiers.meta.Bagging -P 100 -S 1 -num-slots 1 -I 10 -W weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -- -C 0.25 -M 2
```

Does anyone know what a code representation of this might be?

Ideally, I want to store the classes of the classifier and meta classifier in a database table, i.e. so line:

```
Object obj = Class.forName("weka.classifiers.trees.J48").newInstance();
```

becomes:

```
Object obj = Class.forName(classifier.getWekaClass()).newInstance();
```

And where the parameters could be listed in a database table as well to make them easy to change if I swap over classifiers from J48 to NB.

I believe that this is what I'm looking for but...

[http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code#Attribute selection-Meta-Classifier](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code#Attribute%20selection-Meta-Classifier)

Answer (score 0):

The [javadoc](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc/weka/classifiers/meta/Bagging.html) suggests that there is a method `setClassifier()` that you would use to set the classifier you want to use. Beyond that, it's simply a matter of instantiating the class and setting the options accordingly.

You can of course store the class names in a database and use them as an your example. Storing parameters would be a bit trickier as the number and type would vary with each classifier -- you would have to provide a wrapper that can serialise and deserialise them properly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply: I plan a 'one size fits all' varchar field in a database table. This can be read to a Java string at runtime. The string can then be split to suit cls.setOptions(optionsArray);

It's the use of the meta classifier that gets me though.

Comment: You would need to store that information separately as the classifier would be instantiated in a different way (i.e. you would have to set the base classifier).

Comment: If I understand this issue correctly, the base classifier, e.g. J48, would be set normally. It's the application of the meta classifier I'm unsure of.

Comment: The meta classifier is set up in exactly the same way except for the call to `setClassifier()` where you give it the base classifier.

Comment: I've amended the question slightly to include a link to what I think you mean.